# Macro in C not understandable

Tags: c, linux, macros

I was looking at a header file in my linux system. It has a macro defined as:

```
#define INIT_C_CC "\003\034\177\025\004\0\1\0\021\023\032\0\022\017\027\026\0"
```

I do not understand what does this mean? This isn't escape/octal/anything that I could easily find. Please help.

Comment: Which header file exactly? May be you can search for `INIT_C_CC` in the file to understand it's use better.

Comment: @rootkea, I first referenced that only, you can also check this out. http://lxr.oss.org.cn/plain/source/arch/cris/include/asm/termios.h?a=ppc#L13

Comment: Re: "This isn't [...]/octal": Sure it is. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: It pretty clearly *is* octal.

Comment: Lack of anything larger than `7` kinda gives it away?

Comment: @ruakh I thought that because there is a "1" in between without a preceding 0.

Comment: @user5400132: Ah, I see. You're thinking of how something like `int i = 012;` uses the octal integer constant `012` to initialize `i` to ten? But these aren't integer constants, they're escape sequences; just as the `n` in `"\n"` doesn't mean anything like the one in `int i = n`, there's no reason to expect escape sequences to look like integer constants. ``\`` followed by one to three octal digits is an octal escape sequence.

Comment: @rulakh If it is so then why is an escape sequence assigned to an unsigned char?
e.g. unsigned char .c_cc = INIT_C_CC , this is written in the code. I'm confused again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This macro defines a set of special characters used to initialize the cc array in the termios struct. In the termios man page you can see their meaning:

The macro is a sequence of characters in octal representation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Here you can find the ascii in octal representation codes: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/ascii-code-table.html

From: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html

> The c_cc array defines the terminal special characters.  The symbolic
>          indices (initial values) and meaning are:

```
   VDISCARD
          (not in POSIX; not supported under Linux; 017, SI, Ctrl-O)
          Toggle: start/stop discarding pending output.  Recognized when
          IEXTEN is set, and then not passed as input.

   VDSUSP (not in POSIX; not supported under Linux; 031, EM, Ctrl-Y)
          Delayed suspend character (DSUSP): send SIGTSTP signal when
          the character is read by the user program.  Recognized when
          IEXTEN and ISIG are set, and the system supports job control,
          and then not passed as input.

   VEOF   (004, EOT, Ctrl-D) End-of-file character (EOF).  More
          precisely: this character causes the pending tty buffer to be
          sent to the waiting user program without waiting for end-of-
          line.  If it is the first character of the line, the read(2)
          in the user program returns 0, which signifies end-of-file.
          Recognized when ICANON is set, and then not passed as input.

   VEOL   (0, NUL) Additional end-of-line character (EOL).  Recognized
          when ICANON is set.

   VEOL2  (not in POSIX; 0, NUL) Yet another end-of-line character
          (EOL2).  Recognized when ICANON is set.

   VERASE (0177, DEL, rubout, or 010, BS, Ctrl-H, or also #) Erase
          character (ERASE).  This erases the previous not-yet-erased
          character, but does not erase past EOF or beginning-of-line.
          Recognized when ICANON is set, and then not passed as input.

   VINTR  (003, ETX, Ctrl-C, or also 0177, DEL, rubout) Interrupt
          character (INTR).  Send a SIGINT signal.  Recognized when ISIG
          is set, and then not passed as input.

   VKILL  (025, NAK, Ctrl-U, or Ctrl-X, or also @) Kill character
          (KILL).  This erases the input since the last EOF or
          beginning-of-line.  Recognized when ICANON is set, and then
          not passed as input.

   VLNEXT (not in POSIX; 026, SYN, Ctrl-V) Literal next (LNEXT).  Quotes
          the next input character, depriving it of a possible special
          meaning.  Recognized when IEXTEN is set, and then not passed
          as input.

   VMIN   Minimum number of characters for noncanonical read (MIN).

   VQUIT  (034, FS, Ctrl-\) Quit character (QUIT).  Send SIGQUIT signal.
          Recognized when ISIG is set, and then not passed as input.

   VREPRINT
          (not in POSIX; 022, DC2, Ctrl-R) Reprint unread characters
          (REPRINT).  Recognized when ICANON and IEXTEN are set, and
          then not passed as input.

   VSTART (021, DC1, Ctrl-Q) Start character (START).  Restarts output
          stopped by the Stop character.  Recognized when IXON is set,
          and then not passed as input.

   VSTATUS
          (not in POSIX; not supported under Linux; status request: 024,
          DC4, Ctrl-T).  Status character (STATUS).  Display status
          information at terminal, including state of foreground process
          and amount of CPU time it has consumed.  Also sends a SIGINFO
          signal (not supported on Linux) to the foreground process
          group.

   VSTOP  (023, DC3, Ctrl-S) Stop character (STOP).  Stop output until
          Start character typed.  Recognized when IXON is set, and then
          not passed as input.

   VSUSP  (032, SUB, Ctrl-Z) Suspend character (SUSP).  Send SIGTSTP
          signal.  Recognized when ISIG is set, and then not passed as
          input.

   VSWTCH (not in POSIX; not supported under Linux; 0, NUL) Switch
          character (SWTCH).  Used in System V to switch shells in shell
          layers, a predecessor to shell job control.

   VTIME  Timeout in deciseconds for noncanonical read (TIME).

   VWERASE
          (not in POSIX; 027, ETB, Ctrl-W) Word erase (WERASE).
          Recognized when ICANON and IEXTEN are set, and then not passed
          as input.

   An individual terminal special character can be disabled by setting
   the value of the corresponding c_cc element to _POSIX_VDISABLE.

   The above symbolic subscript values are all different, except that
   VTIME, VMIN may have the same value as VEOL, VEOF, respectively.  In
   noncanonical mode the special character meaning is replaced by the
   timeout meaning.  For an explanation of VMIN and VTIME, see the
   description of noncanonical mode below.
```

Comment: can you please tell what is this backslash way of writing? Does this expand as a single string or multiple strings or what? I've seen a variable assigned value equal to INIT_C_CC, what does it mean? What value does that variable have now?

Comment: It's a sequence of characters in octal representation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Answer (score 1):

The replacement text for the `INIT_C_CC` macro is a string literal, where each character is specified as an octal escape sequence.

If used to initialize an array, it expands to

```
char c_cc[17] = "\003\034\177\025\004\0\1\0\021\023\032\0\022\017\027\026\0";
```

which is equivalent to

```
char c_cc[17] = {3, 28, 127, 21, 4, 0, 1, 0, 17, 19, 26, 0, 18, 15, 23, 22, 0 };
```